# Rails 3 - vote_fu - Query for specific vote by a voter on voteable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, plugins

I'm trying to query for a specific vote within the vote_fu plugin so that I can destroy it. I need to do this as I've implemented the one vote per user policy, but I'd like user's to be able to remove votes.

So what I have is a Link model, which is voteable, and User as the voter. In theory, should I not be able to do something like:

```
@link.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).destroy
```

Though votes is not a support method due to it not being a table I built in the db. I've read through vote_fu's documentation, and I can't really seem to find/or figure out how I'm supposed to destroying votes.

```
def destroy
      @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
      @vote.destroy

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(user_votes_url) }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      end
    end
```

Is in vote_fu's lib, so I should be able to call a destroy on the vote, I just need to be able to find the vote.

Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going about this the wrong way. My final code is as follows:

```
def unvote
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    @vote = current_user.votes.find_by_voteable_id(@link.id)
    @vote.destroy
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Then in my view:

```
<%= link_to "Delete Vote", unvote_topic_link_path(@topic, link), :method => :delete %>
```

and my route if you want the whole picture of everything going on:

```
resources :links do
      member do
        post 'vote'
        delete 'unvote'
```